# How to show queries logs

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, logging, app-config, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a rails 4 application, and I want to see sql queries that are been executed in my application.

In my config/environment/development.rb:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

But is not enough to show queries generated by my rails application.

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.1

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]
```

When I start my rails server, the queries is not showed.

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-06-21 13:55:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-06-21 13:55:18] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [i686-linux]
[2014-06-21 13:55:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6623 port=3000
I, [2014-06-21T13:55:21.869432 #6623]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-21 13:55:21 -0300
I, [2014-06-21T13:55:21.869538 #6623]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-21 13:55:21 -0300
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (9.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 17.9ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
I, [2014-06-21T13:55:23.538983 #6623]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-21 13:55:23 -0300
I, [2014-06-21T13:55:23.542594 #6623]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-21 13:55:23 -0300
I, [2014-06-21T13:55:23.579254 #6623]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-21 13:55:23 -0300
I, [2014-06-21T13:55:23.579456 #6623]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-21 13:55:23 -0300
```

Here is a example of what I'm looking for:

```
User Load (0.003154)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) - (user.rb, line 24)
```

Some one have any idea about what i need to do?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display SQL queries in log with Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397341/display-sql-queries-in-log-with-rails-4)

Comment: OK. I had read this article before.. but its not solve my problem..

Comment: What is `RAILS_ENV` set to?

Comment: The rails server says it is started in development.

Comment: I did it in development..